# Closing the "Styles and Formatting" pane in Word XP with the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word

I'm using Word from Office XP and I want to close the "Styles and Formatting" pane using the keyboard alone. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 it is ALT+CTRL+SHIFT+S, but not sure if it applies to your version.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'd be happy for a shortcut that closes *any* active pane, not specifically the "Styles and Formatting" one.

Comment: There are ways to edit keyboard shortcuts by going into tools>customize then click on commands tab and rearrange. Not sure if this is a selectable command, but this may get you closer to what you need. Here is a link that describes how to do this - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/assign-or-change-a-keyboard-accelerator-HP003089372.aspx

Comment: I looked at it. There's a `ClosePane` command which seems like it should do exactly what I want, but I tried pressing its shortcut,  `Alt-Shift-C`, while the focus is on the "Styles and Formatting" pane, and nothing happened! I even tried assigning a different key-combination to it and it didn't help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this article:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-style-HP001026134.aspx

I don't think assign a short cut key applies to the task pane but to one of the Styles and Formatting you want to use that is avaiable on the pane.