# Word keyboard shortcut to close apply styles popup

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

In modern MS Word (Office 365) there are keyboard shortcuts to open different pop-up panes. These are handy if you like me prefer to work mostly with keyboard.

As example, the "Apply Styles" pane, shortcut `CTRL SHIFT S` which opens and puts focus on this window:
[image: Word (Office365) Apply Style pane opened in document]

But how is it possible using **keyboard** to **CLOSE** the window ? Some old posts on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/219747/closing-the-styles-and-formatting-pane-in-word-xp-with-the-keyboard) and [msoffice forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/closing-apply-styles-from-the-keyboard/9f6b291c-38c6-4509-a960-01a80263f14c) suggest `CTRL SPACE` followed by `C` but that does not open the window menu. `ALT F4` closes Word.   `ESC` does nothing.

Is there no way today other than using mouse ?

Comment: (the shown window is titled "Anvend typografier", since my locale is `da-dk` for Office

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
seems to have disappeared from Word 365.
Until it is reintroduced by Microsoft, the only solution I see
is to use a VBA macro, like the following:

```vb
Sub CloseApplyStyles()
  If CommandBars("Apply Styles").Enabled Then    'Check if it is open
    CommandBars("Apply Styles").Visible = False
  End If
End Sub
```

The document needs to be saved in macro-enabled format (`.docm`).

Some resources I found to help you create this macro:

- [Show the developer tab in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/show-the-developer-tab-in-word-e356706f-1891-4bb8-8d72-f57a51146792)
- [Walkthrough: Call code from VBA in a Visual Basic project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-from-vba-in-a-visual-basic-project?view=vs-2022)
- [Word Macro Examples & VBA Tutorial](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/word/macro-examples)
- [How to assign VBA to a keyboard shortcut in Microsoft Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1736457/how-to-assign-vba-to-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-microsoft-word)

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking for this for years. Generally, I use both the Styles Pane and the legacy Styles Dropdown. This gives me one more thing for my toolbox. https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#StylesQATAddIn --- I posted this in the original question on the Microsoft Answers forum. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/closing-apply-styles-from-the-keyboard/9f6b291c-38c6-4509-a960-01a80263f14c

Comment: @harrymc thank you for this. It should be noted that the CommandBar does not have an instance (Enable) before you use it **first time**, and this instance is kept, even if you set it non visible. Not at all clear for the user. So you need to encapsulate the above in something like `If CommandBars("Apply Styles").Enabled Then... `.  I updated the version to `..visible = Not (..).Visible` to toggle it. See also [this](https://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=34192).